# How do I output Windows Service project from TFS Build Definition

Tags: windows, service, tfs, build, definition

I have an existing build definition that builds multiple solutions and each of those has one or more webapps or wcf service projects. Those all get built and copied to _PublishedWebsites. But I have a new project that is a plain Windows Service (NT Service) that does not get separated out into an installable location.

What must I do to have this also copied out like the other ones?

Answer (score 0):

The publish settings in the website application control that. If you want to create a build for your service to output similarly, you can customize the build workflow to create a folder to output all the files. For more information on customize binaries folders see the following links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff977206.aspx

http://lajak.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/customize-binaries-folder-in-tfs-team-build-part-2/

If you mean you want to create a MSI project that will setup the Windows service you can use WIX. For more information see the following link:

http://wix.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks all, but I was looking for a much simpler isolated solution. We have over 80 projects that are built with this config and this one project is the only one that needs special care. I decided to use a very simple bat file and post-build step to call it, which required no changes to the solution or the build definition.